# Firewall IP-Filtered Pinhole Risks

Tags: firewalls, rdp

To facilitate consulting work, a client has suggested that they allow me to connect directly to an in-house remote desktop server, via a firewall pinhole which allows connection from my IP address only.  My IP isn't static, but it hasn't changed in years, and if it did they would update the firewall rule.

Their solution means no need for a VPN, but also means I would have to VPN to my office before connecting when I'm on the road (which I'm ok with).

Apart from a reflection DDOS attack aimed at that one port (with knowledge of my IP), is there any specific security risk to them associated with this?  As I understand it, the RDP session traffic itself is secure.

I had a surprisingly hard time finding discussion on this topic when searching, any advice would be great.

Comment: The relevant details appear to come in drips and it is unclear whether or not you have provided all the details. Can you summarise the full details? RDP presents a range of risks. VPN presents risks. Whatever is on the other side of the firewall port presents risks. Are there more details to share?

Comment: @schroeder Can you help me understand what other details would make sense? I have a laptop running a current version of the MS RDP client, connecting to a Windows Server acting as a RDP Host.    The desktop is on my local (natted) LAN, the server is on their corporate (natted) LAN.  Their firewall would allow me to connect directly from my laptop to their server, but only if the connection originates from my public IP.